# Change TextView positions if text inside is too long

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two textviews like this:

```
=======================
= TextView1 TextView2 =
=======================
```

And I would like to detect when the textviews are too long such that they are displayed like this:

```
=======================
=      TextView1      =
=      TextView2      =
=======================
```

currently for longer text, it is displayed like this:

```
=======================
= TextView1 Text      =
=           View2     =
=======================
```

Is it possible to do it without measuring text lenght for screen ?

UPDATE:

Position with short text:
Button's width should be the same even 1 text is longer then 2.

[image]

Button positions if text is longer then place to take
[image]

Any advices ?

Comment: firstly specify that are you using Java or Kotlin?

Comment: You can use [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) to achieve exact results.

Comment: I would like to not use any 3rd part library for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have make this type of design using [FlexBox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

```xml
    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:flexWrap="wrap">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="long text"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"/>
    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: I'm not sure how this should work. When I add long text into buttons they are just a bit bigger and text is splitted into to lines but text should be still in 1 line and buttons should change orientation to vertical but it's not working this way. Any idea ?

Comment: Second problem is I need to have the same width for the buttons even if 1 text is long and 2 is short